# Troubles with execlp's output and pipes

Tags: c, exec, pipe, stdout

I'm writing a program that has an interface like:
myprog file1 file2 c

This program creates two children and P2 with an execlp opens file2, makes a grep -c on this file for founding c and gives the results to his brother P1 (I have to do it closing the STDOUT's FD and dupping the pipe p2p1 between them). P1 receives this from p2p1 and sends this value to P0. Moreover this also makes the same thing with file1 and gives the result to P0, which will print them.

The problem is: the father P0 reads something, but it is wrong.

What I'm supposed to do? Here's the code and thanks for your attention.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 128


/**************************/
/* DICHIARAZIONE FUNZIONI */
/**************************/
void wait_child();
void processo_p2(char *inputfile, char *c);
void processo_p1(char *inputfile, char *c);

/*********************/
/* VARIABILI GLOBALI */
/*********************/
int p1p0[2], p2p1[2];


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pid[2], i, value, count=0;
    char *c, buf[10];

    if (argc !=4) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Numero di argomenti errato\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file1 file2 C\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    c=argv[3];

    /* Init */

    pipe(p1p0);
    pipe(p2p1);

    for (i=0; i<2; i++) 
    {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "P0: Errore nella fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid[i] == 0) 
        {
            if (i==0) /*P1*/
            {
                close(p1p0[0]);
                close(p2p1[1]);
                sleep(1);
                    processo_p1(argv[1], c);
                    close(p2p1[0]);
        close(p1p0[1]);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else if (i==1)
        {
            close(p2p1[0]);
            close(p1p0[0]);
            close(p1p0[1]);
            processo_p2(argv[2],c);
            close(p2p1[1]);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("P0: created child P%d with PID %d\n", i+1, pid[i]);
        close(p2p1[0]);
        close(p2p1[1]);
        close(p1p0[1]);
    }
} 
i=0;
int nread;
while ( (nread = read(p2p1[0], &buf[i], sizeof(char)) ) > 0 ) {
    i++;
buf[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n",buf);

for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    wait_child();
}

return 0;
}

void processo_p2(char *inputfile, char *c)
{
int fd, nread, i=0, found=0;
char temp, row[100];

close(1);
dup(p2p1[1]);
execlp("grep", "grep", "-c", c, inputfile, (char *)0);
perror("P2: errorr in exec");
close(1);
}

void processo_p1(char *inputfile, char *c)
{
int fd, nrw, sk, nread, p2=0, i=0;
int value=1;
char temp, row[100], buf[10];

//RECEIVING DATA FROM P2 AND SENDING TO P0

while ( (nread = read(p2p1[0], &buf[i], sizeof(char)) ) > 0 ) {
    i++;
}
buf[i] = '\0';
printf("from p2: %s\n",buf); //NOTHING STAMPED
write(p1p0[1],&buf,strlen(buf)+1);

close(1);
dup(p1p0[1]);
execlp("grep", "grep", "-c", c, inputfile, (char *)0);
perror("P1: errore in exec");
close(p1p0[1]);
}


void wait_child() {
int pid_terminated,status;

pid_terminated=wait(&status);
if (pid_terminated < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", getpid());
    perror("P0: errore in wait");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if(WIFEXITED(status))
{
    printf("P0: terminazione volontaria del figlio %d con stato %d\n",
            pid_terminated, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == EXIT_FAILURE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "P0: errore nella terminazione del figlio pid_terminated\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
else if(WIFSIGNALED(status))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "P0: terminazione involontaria del figlio %d a causa del segnale %d\n",
            pid_terminated,WTERMSIG(status));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific than 'reads something wrong'.

Comment: @bmargulies thanks for your interest. Before having from grep in P2 the error bad file descriptor (i edited something) the grep worked, but p1 received some data that were not int nor string... so wrong values. Honestly now i dunno why it is saying bad file descriptor, grep wants only the name of the file... ps: i have also permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Trivia (but it stops the code compiling):* The code shown originally has a close brace in the wrong place — the functions are all apparently embedded inside `main()`.  The last brace should be moved up the file considerably.

In the loop that launches the child processs, you have the parent process execute:

```
    printf("P0: created child P%d with PID %d\n", i+1, pid[i]);
    close(p2p1[0]);
    close(p2p1[1]);
    close(p1p0[1]);
```

In the parent process, immediately after the loop, you have:

```
int nread;
while ( (nread = read(p2p1[0], &buf[i], sizeof(char)) ) > 0 ) {
    i++;
buf[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n",buf);

for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    wait_child();
}

return 0;
}
```

'Tis a pity that you closed the file descriptor you're trying to read from.  The parent should be reading from `p1p0[0]`, which you did leave open.

Fixes:

- Move the set of three closes out of the loop.
- Read from the correct file descriptor.
- Insert a missing close brace for the `while` loop shown, or remove its open brace.

---

The question in the comments has, as usual for comments, inscrutable code.  The problem though is that you have too big a loop.

This is what the tail of my fixed version of your `main()` function looks like:

```
 …rest of loop to launch children…
        else
        {
            printf("P0: created child P%d with PID %d\n", i + 1, pid[i]);
        }
    }

    close(p2p1[0]);
    close(p2p1[1]);
    close(p1p0[1]);

    i = 0;
    int nread;
    while ((nread = read(p1p0[0], &buf[i], sizeof(char)) ) > 0)
        i++;
    buf[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        wait_child();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Given that I saved the source code in a file `pip.c` and created the program `pip` from it, a sample run produced:

```
$ ./pip pip.c pip.c c
P0: created child P1 with PID 75458
P0: created child P2 with PID 75459
from p2: 49

49

P0: terminazione volontaria del figlio 75459 con stato 0
P0: terminazione volontaria del figlio 75458 con stato 0
$
```

I'm not entirely happy with all the newlines, but at least the same answer is given twice, as it obviously should be.

Comment: thank you for reply.
I edited it as shown:
    
int nread;while ( (nread = read(p1p0[0], &buf[i], sizeof(char)) ) > 0 ) {
        i++;
    close(p1p0[0]);
    buf[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",buf);

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        wait_child();
    }

and leaved the closes as they are (parent doesn't need the write side of p1p0 and neither both of p2p1) but the problem is still unsolved.

In particular, the function "processo_p2" sends data with p2p1 to "processo_p1", but the printf inside of it doesn't stamp anything.

Any hint about this?

Comment: EDIT: i don't know why now is not identing the text... sorry

In other words, i fixed the right pipe on read and closed after while, but still not works.

Comment: thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. 
I would like to know why moving out the 3 close from the else statement it works... Why is so important to put them on the bottom of the code? 'cause my Ph says you have to close unused resources ASAP and I want to be sure this is not the case for another solution.

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop, you close those three descriptors in the parent process, so when it repeats to create the second child, you've closed the pipe that's supposed to be used to communicate between the children, which leads to things not working well.  Additionally, on the second iteration of the loop, you're reclosing already closed file descriptors.